# GWT SimpleHtmlSanitizer

Tags: gwt

Here is what I am trying to do. We are using Klockwork static analysis tools to determine weaknesses in our GWT application.

We have an `ExportServlet` that exports information. Before writing it out we construct the `HttpResponse` like so,

```
final String designName = req.getParameter("designName");
resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + designName + ".xls\"");         
resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
resp.setContentLength(output.length());
final ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
out.print(output);
out.flush();
```

Klockwork complains that since `designName` is being used on the response Header it needs to be validated for XSS vulnerabilities. In particular it suggests to remove carriage returns and line feeds from the input. Will GWT's `SimpleHtmlSanitizer.sanitize(input)` remove those characters?

Answer (score 2):

The CR/LF removal requirement of clockworks is most likely for safeguarding against  [HTTP header injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_header_injection) vulnerability. CR/LF are completely safe as far as HTML is concerned, therefore HTML sanitizers will always leave them unchanged.

You should probably create an Http header sanitization method that removes CR/LF. I don't think that any browser will execute a script embedded in an http header so doing html sanitization on headers might not give any benefit.

Answer (score 1):

String concatenated in different contexts should be sanitized in different ways. SimpleHtmlSanitizer sanitizes strings about to be inserted into html code, using it here is wrong. For Content-Disposition header, I use the following method. It does support international characters in file names, and escapes all special characters, including space and newlines.

```
private static final char[] HEX_CHARS = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();

public static String encodeContentDispositionFilename(String fname) {
    byte[] bytes;
    try {
        bytes = fname.getBytes("utf-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    int i=0, l=bytes.length;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("filename*=UTF-8''");
    while (i<l) {
        if (bytes[i] >= '0' && bytes[i] <= '9' || bytes[i] >= 'a' && bytes[i] <= 'z' || bytes[i] >= 'A' && bytes[i] <= 'Z'
                || bytes[i] == '.' || bytes[i] == '_')
            sb.append((char)bytes[i]);
        else
            sb
                .append('%')
                .append(HEX_CHARS[(bytes[i] >> 4) & 0xf])
                .append(HEX_CHARS[bytes[i] & 0xF]);
        i++;
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Now rewrite your code like this:

```
final String designName = req.getParameter("designName");
final String escaped = encodeContentDispositionFilename(designName + ".xls");
resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; " + escaped);         
// ...
```

For information about various escape contexts, see http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2009/03/reducing-xss-by-way-of-automatic.html.

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off using [`SafeHtmlUtils#htmlEscape`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SafeHtmlUtils.html#htmlEscape%28java.lang.String%29) or [`SafeHtmlUtils#htmlEscapeAllowEntities`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SafeHtmlUtils.html#htmlEscapeAllowEntities%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks. On further investigation, SimpleHtmlSanitizer.sanitize internally relies on SafeHtmlUtils#htmlEscapeAllowEntities.

Comment: Thanks. On further investigation, SimpleHtmlSanitizer.sanitize internally relies on SafeHtmlUtils#htmlEscapeAllowEntities. The problem that I have is to escape carriage return and line feeds for instance I if I pass "untitled\n" to these methods I get back unchanged result. These utilities look for unsafe HTML only. For now I m using <inputString>.replace("\r\n", "").trim(); and then passing it to the sanitizer.